# Unable to merge multiple 16bit/32bit images into a single HDR image using OpenCV Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

It seems that OpenCV's built-in HDR merge operations (ie: createMergeDebevec) expects 8bit/channel image inputs, but because RAW sources like CR2s are 14 bit, I have them converted to 16 bit or 32bit images.

Here is the error I get when trying to merge 16 or 32bit bit images:

> Assertion failed (images[0].depth() == CV_8U) in
>   cv::CalibrateDebevecImpl::process

Is there a way to get around the 8bit limitation of HDR merge operations in OpenCV?